# What is the function of `Library/Application Support/updater_mcy/updater_mcy` file?

Tags: error, malware, virus, anti-virus

My Avast security app has isolated the following file:

`Library/Application Support/updater_mcy/updater_mcy`

Since this has happened, I think it has resulted in me getting error messages on my Mac saying that some software will not be compatible in the future. Was it justified to have this file isolated by Avast or should I put it back?

Answer (score 1):

[Virustotal thinks it's ad-ware](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/9530d481f7bb07aac98a46357bfcff96e2936a90571b4629ae865a2ce63e5c8e/analysis/1458973247/), based on the name alone.

You can double-check by [uploading the file](https://www.virustotal.com/en/) independently to them & see if it agrees.